# Stone Tower Imagery

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda, majoras-mask

In the Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask, the final dungeon of the game is the unceremoniously named "Stone Tower" in the haunted region of Ikana.

Little definitive information on the structure is directly given to us in the game, leading to much speculation, but I personally subscribe to a view akin to that found in this article: https://www.zeldadungeon.net/the_message_of_majoras_mask1/

I recently was exploring the temple with a bit more attention to the details of the temple. (I am studying the 3DS remake). The temple is chock-full of interesting imagery, such as the large head at the entrance that is actually just an inverted sculpture of Majora's Mask.

There are a number of designs that are somewhat reminiscent of demonic reimaginings of the Four Giants, a number of profane and even Triforce-denouncing imagery around as well.

I was wondering—what is all of the imagery/designs in the Stone Tower, and what might it represent?

Comment: I suspect that like a lot of background art in games/shows/films, the intention is for it to be *evocative* rather than something that stands up to close scrutiny

Comment: I don't disagree; however, there is some very specific imagery in this game that is extremely easy to look over at a first glance, leading to the possibility (if not likelihood) of hidden secrets/